# upload photo to facebook returning "expects upload file"

Tags: visual-c++, facebook-graph-api, winhttp

I am using the following code to upload photo to facebook

```
hconnect = WinHttpConnect(hsession,L"graph.facebook.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT,0);`hrequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hconnect, L"POST", reqUrl,NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

            CString temp = L"Source:";
            temp += objDlg.fileName;

            bResult =  WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hrequest,temp,(ULONG)-1L,WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD );

            CString contentType(L"Content-Type:multipart/form-data");

            bResult =  WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hrequest,contentType,(ULONG)-1L,WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD );bResult = WinHttpSendRequest( hrequest,WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,objDlg.fileLength, NULL);
                if(bResult)
                {
                    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
                    bResult = WinHttpWriteData( hrequest,objDlg.memblock, objDlg.fileLength,&dwBytesWritten);}`
```

but its returning "Expects Upload file as reponse.

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faceebook expects the post data in a "multipart/form-data" format. Form the data accordingly and send the data along with Winhttpsendrequest. The photo  gets uploaded and the corresponding ID will be returned.